# Isosceles triangle height question

Tags: trigonometry

I am a production designer for an upcoming film, and I have a high school geometry/trig question because I'm wondering whether we can fit a set piece through a tight door. Here is what I need:

There is an isosceles triangle. The base measures 72 inches across and it is 4ft high. A what height in the triangle would a line, going parallel to the base line, be measured at 18 inches from side to side of the triangle?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: I think most people here use the metric system. If you use the english one, then *at least* use the same units. Is it true that $\;1\,ft=12\;$ inches? I honestly ask: I am not used to that system.

Comment: It goes proportionally from $0$ at the top to $72$ at the bottom: distance from top $/4=18/72$.

Answer (score 1):

Joint the midpoints of both legs. This segment of line is automatically parallel to the base and half its length, thus $\;\frac{72}2=36\;$ inches (this is a theorem in Euclidean geometry).

Now look at the upper triangle: it also is isosceles and its base is $\;36\;$ inches long. Again, join the midpoints of this triangle's legs, and as before this midsegment is $\;\frac{36}2=18\;$ inches long, and you are $\;\frac42+\frac22=3\;$ feet from the base.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much!!